# How to put the VBA code contained in code module in sheet module

Tags: vba, excel, module, label, caption

I have a button in the "code module" which runs a request. Next to the Button is a label included which shows a check mark a soon as the button has finished running.

The button code is in the code modul. The codes for the label with the check mark is inlcuded in the workbook and sheet modul.

Now, the issue is when I push the button it runs perfectly fine and does what it supposed to but the label with the check mark does not get activated. The reason might be because I have not included/referenced the workbook/sheet modul in my code modul. Hope for a bit help.

[image]

Code in workbook Module:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call Tabelle1.prcResetLabels
End Sub
```

Code in Sheet Module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Schaltfläche2_Klicken()
Call prcSetLabel(probjLabel:=Label1)
End Sub

Private Sub prcSetLabel(ByRef probjLabel As MSForms.Label)
With probjLabel
.Caption = "P"
End With
End Sub

Friend Sub prcResetLabels()
Dim objOLEObject As OLEObject
For Each objOLEObject In OLEObjects
   With objOLEObject
        If .progID = "Forms.Label.1" Then _
           .Object.Caption = vbNullString
   End With
Next
End Sub
```

Code in Codemodul:

```
Public Sub Schaltfläche2_Klicken()
With Sheets("Table1")
  .Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Environ("USERNAME")
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Declare your module sub as public. Also, what is Friend Sub?

Comment: The Freind Sub is the code to clear all check marks afterwards. I have renamed "Private" to " Public" in the code modul but the  sheet module still doesnt get activated.

Comment: OK.. I am very sorry to be this guy but I have no idea what your issue is. Please make sure that in the problem description the current behaviour and the desired behaviour is clearly distinguishable and that the problem is clear. A problem is always the difference between desired and current behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean by activated? And prefix the sub with the module name.

Comment: Thanks to  Lucas Raphael Pianegonda i have rephrased the the porblem a bit. By activated I mean when the button is pushed the label (which is reponsible for the check mark) doesnt run as the link  between the codemodul for the button and the sheet modul for the label is missing perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ist simple this:

```
 Sub Schaltfläche2_Klicken()
 Call prcResetLabels
 With Sheets("Table1")
 .Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Environ("USERNAME")
 End With
 Call prcSetLabel(probjLabel:=Table1.Label1)
 End Sub

 Private Sub prcSetLabel(ByVal probjLabel As Object)
 With probjLabel
 .Object.Caption = "P"
 End With
 End Sub
 Public Sub prcResetLabels()
 Dim objOLEObject As OLEObject

 For Each objOLEObject In Table1.OLEObjects
 With objOLEObject
     If .progID = "Forms.Label.1" Then _
        .Object.Caption = vbNullString
 End With
 Next
 End Sub
```